# Swift 3 - How to write functions with no initialisers like the new UIColors?

Tags: swift, function, swift3

In previous versions of swift, you would get the colour white like this `UIColor.whiteColor()`

However, in Swift 3, you get the colour white without initialisers like so `UIColor.white`

How would I write this same function without having to use initialisers, as `UIColor.custom` ?

```
extension UIColor {
    func custom() {
        return UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift 2, `whiteColor()` is a class function. In Swift 3, `white` is a class variable. (It isn't about *initialisers*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [computed properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259):

```
extension UIColor {
    static var custom: UIColor {
        return UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably right, but the complier will force you to use capital letters on your color (variable) name since its static. I wonder why the inbuilt colors you get from UIKit does not have capital letters:  UIColor.red What do you think?

Comment: @knutigro have you any source for that? I tried the code above in a playground and it worked. And in one of my projects, I'm using similar code very often and it compiles without errors. And according to the API Design Guidelines, `var`s should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Aha sorry about this.. I now realized that I got this warning from a 3d party app I have installed called Swift-Clean  http://www.swiftcleanapp.com. I guess they are not up to date with Swift 3 yet.

Answer (score 3):

`.whiteColor()` is a [static method (type method)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID241) on `UIColor`, whereas `.white` is a static [(computed in my example) property](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259) on `UIColor`. The difference in defining them looks like:

```
struct Color {
  let red: Int
  let green: Int
  let blue: Int

  static func whiteColor() -> Color {
    return Color(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255)
  }

  static var white: Color {
    return Color(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They are properties, not functions.

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
  // Read-only computed property allows you to omit the get keyword
  static var custom: UIColor { return UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 3.0:**

in `UIColor.white`, `white` is a **property** and not a method/initializer

**In earlier swift versions:**

in `UIColor.whiteColor()`, `white` was a `type method`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored class property instead of a computed class property.

```
extension UIColor {
    static let custom = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1)
}
```

--

*NOTE: Old answer. Previously Objective C didn't allow for class properties, now it does.*

Like others have said, it's a property.

If you're only using Swift (no Objective C), then you can use a regular class property instead of a computed property.

```
extension UIColor {
    @nonobjc static let custom = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1)
}
```

Comment: just curious to know why `@nonobjc static` var rather than `static` ?

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard There was a time when Objective C didn't allow class properties. This is no longer the case. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler can infer the type of the value you are going to need, like here

```
let a: Foo = ...
```

you can use a static member (method, function, stored property, computed property) omitting the name of the type.

So given this type

```
class Foo {
    static let a = Foo()
    static var b = Foo()
    static var c:Foo { return Foo() }
    static func d() -> Foo { return Foo() }
}
```

you can write

```
let a: Foo = .a
let b: Foo = .b
let c: Foo = .c
let d: Foo = .d()
```

The same technique can be used when you pass a value to a function

```
func doNothing(foo: Foo) { }
```

Again the type of the parameter can be inferred by the compiler so instead of writing

```
doNothing(foo: Foo.a)
```

you can simply write

```
doNothing(foo: .a)
```